# Why is vim loading /etc/vimrc differently on startup vs source command

Tags: linux, vim

Why is vim behaving differently with some `/etc/vimrc` settings when I startup vim vs when I `:source /etc/vimrc`?

Scenario: I'm editing a PHP file and there's some plugin behavior I don't like so I disable the filetype plugin in a `/etc/vimrc.custom` sourced from `/etc/vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin off
```

This works as expected when I `:source /etc/vimrc` (`:verbose filetype` correctly reports `filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:ON`) but when I just startup vim on the file it's clear the plugin is on (`:verbose filetype` reports `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`).

`/etc/vimrc` is the default with `source /etc/vimrc.custom` added at the bottom.

As a test, if I `:source /etc/vimrc.custom` directly in a vim session it does the right thing (`:verbose filetype` correctly reports `filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:ON`).

Update: The existence of ~/.vimrc matters (empty or not) as it changes the loading of scripts as shown by `:scriptnames`. Significantly. Most importantly, for me, /usr/share/vim/vim82/indent.php is loaded and overrides formatoptions without a ~/.vimrc while indent.php is not loaded when ~/.vimrc is present (can even be empty).

Update: Since Vim 8.0, $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim is loaded if no ~/.vimrc exists. See `:help defaults.vim`. This file is loaded after /etc/vimrc which explains why it's overriding customizations to /etc/vimrc or scripts sourced from it. To override this behavior, add `let skip_defaults_vim = 1` to /etc/vimrc or whatever vimrc file you're using.

Comment: Read `:help startup` and put your user configuration into `~/.vimrc` or (even better) `~/.vim/vimrc`. Don't mess with the system configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for the `:help startup` tip. It's important this is a global configuration. Any reason why you suggest not to mess with system configuration files?

Comment: It leads to problems such as yours :-p Really, system config changes stuff for all your users (do you want that?), user config is given precedence over system config and I suspect your settings are getting overridden by `defaults.vim` in the absence of user config. Maybe I misunderstand your question and you might have a point in using system config. It might be hard to impossible to force a certain setting.

Comment: User preferences being set locally in the user's $HOME is the norm. It doesn't have to be explained but deviating from the norm definitely has to be explained and justified.

Comment: It's just that my question is about the technical reasons for vim's startup behavior and using other files is a valid topic but not part of this question

Comment: `:h defaults.vim` So you need to have user vimrc anyway in order to override the defaults.

Comment: Ah, that is helpful. I had just noticed the existence or not of ~/.vimrc affected :scriptnames loading content + order and the help describes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since Vim 8.0, $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim is loaded if no ~/.vimrc exists.

See `:help defaults.vim`

The defaults.vim file is loaded after /etc/vimrc which explains why it's overriding customizations to /etc/vimrc or scripts sourced from it.

To override this behavior, add `let skip_defaults_vim = 1` to /etc/vimrc or whatever vimrc file you're using.

Comment: Another victim of `defaults.vim`.

Comment: ... or the stubborn refusal to put user config where it belongs.